# Removing specific text on a dataTable

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

Hi i have this project that need to load image into datagridview in asp.net webform written in vb
i able to get the location string of the image on the database but the path stored in the database is the pysical path of the image and i know that i cannot load image on gridview from a pysical path, so the way i think is to remove some text on the result from query in dataTable ,
but i don't know if it is possible.
the path in the database is already exist and store by other web appps.

example path query result

```
C:\Users\nx011116\Documents\IQAv2\iqa2005\UploadFiles\19MKAK-20191209009\abenson.png
```

expaected result

```
UploadFiles\19MKAK-20191209009\abenson.png
```

here's my code on getting the data

```
 ds = objIQADataClass.IQA_Attachment_Get(txtCAR.Text.Trim, "B")
 Dim dt As DataTable
 dt = ds.Tables(0)

dgAttachment.DataSource = dt
dgAttachment.DataBind()
```

design part:

```html
  <asp:DataGrid ID="dgAttachment" runat="server" Visible="True" Font-Size="Smaller" Font-Names="Arial" PageSize="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True" GridLines="Vertical" CellPadding="3" BackColor="White" BorderWidth="1px" BorderStyle="None" BorderColor="#999999" SelectedItemStyle-BackColor="LightGreen" HorizontalAlign="Center">
         <SelectedItemStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#CCFFFF"></SelectedItemStyle>
<AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="Gainsboro"></AlternatingItemStyle>
<ItemStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#EEEEEE"></ItemStyle>
<HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" BackColor="Navy"></HeaderStyle>
<FooterStyle ForeColor="Black" BackColor="#CCCCCC"></FooterStyle>
<Columns>
<asp:ButtonColumn Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete">
<HeaderStyle ForeColor="White" BackColor="Navy"></HeaderStyle>
</asp:ButtonColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="Files">
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="White" CssClass="NormalWhite" BackColor="Navy"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkAttachment" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FILENAME")%>'
CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FILENAME")%>' OnCommand="DownloadFile">
</asp:LinkButton>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<%--new--%>
<asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="picture">
<HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" ForeColor="White" CssClass="NormalWhite" BackColor="Navy"></HeaderStyle>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ='<%# Eval("FILENAME")%>' height="120px" Width="150px" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn Visible="false">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="lblFileId" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FILEID") %>'>
</asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
</Columns>
<PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" ForeColor="#330099" Position="Top" BackColor="White" Mode="NumericPages"></PagerStyle>
</asp:DataGrid>
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Hope you understand what i mean

here's what i have try

```
  <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl ='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, Server.MapPath("DataItem.FILENAME"))%>' height="120px" Width="150px" />
```

gives me error

Comment: Look into using the `Server.MapPath` method.

Comment: i don't see any solution on that

Comment: Really? You don't think that a method that converts a local file path to a URL would be useful to display images by URL in a web page?  OK then.

Comment: no i mean i dont know how i will apply it into my code

Comment: i realy suck at english

Comment: Why not add a `OnItemDataBound` event and add a breakpoint in the code-behind and manipulate the data there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i already solve by using this code on the gridview image url

```
ImageUrl ='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.FILENAME").Substring(HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath.Length).Replace("\\", "/")%>'
```

and i tink my question tittle is in corrent